# ¿Por qué al añadir un caracter a un StringBuilder me devuelve NullPointerException, no siendo null caracter?

Tags: java, string, io, nullpointerexception

Haciendo debugging, el valor de `caracter` durante la primera lectura y hasta que alcanza el StringBuilder `hora` (línea 12), es el 48, equivalente al 0 al convertir en ASCII.

Sin embargo, al alcanzar la línea 12: `hora.append(caracter)`, me devuelve la excepción `java.lang.NullPointerException`

**¿A qué puede deberse dicha excepción?**

Mi código es el siguiente

```
public void readFromToSa(){
    FileReader reader=null;
    try{
        source= new File("./miArchivo.txt");
        reader= new FileReader(source);
        int caracter;
        while((caracter= reader.read())!=-1){
            if(caracter==0){
                break;
            }
            if(caracter!=32){  //(char)32: espacio
                hora.append(caracter);
            }else{
                horas.add(hora.toString());
                //Vaciar StringBuilder guardando valor y volver a realizar el proceso
            }
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has inicializado la variable `hora`? Tiene pinta de que es eso.

Comment: Si, como null, `private StringBuilder hora=null;`

Comment: @JD0001 Pues ahí está el `NullPointerException`, la has inicializado a `null`. Usa `private StringBuilder hora = new StringBuilder();`

Comment: Cierto, que torpeza la mia! habre relacionado la inicialización de StringBuilder con la de String.. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en que era necesaria la inicialización del objeto `StringBuilder hora`.

En mi caso lo inicializaba con un valor null, de ahi que devolviera la excepción NullPointerException.

Gracias a @Jose D. Jurado por su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56554/por-qu%c3%a9-al-a%c3%b1adir-un-caracter-a-un-stringbuilder-me-devuelve-nullpointerexcepti#comment101317_56554)

> ```
> @JD0001 Pues ahí está el NullPointerException, la has inicializado a null.
> Usa private StringBuilder hora = new StringBuilder();
> ```